# Javascript function to only allow decimal number with 2 decimal points in a textbox while typing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp textbox and I would like to set up a javascript function to only allow people to enter decimal values with 2 numbers beyond the decimal point. For example:

`43432131 - good`

`54525582.23 - good`

`3423.3 - good`

`.23 - good`

`45573490.343 - bad`

`34.34.34 - bad`

`345..23 - bad`

You get the idea. I have an existing function with a regex that sort of works.

```
    function fnCurrencyOnly(o) {
        var sValue = o.value;
        var sKey = String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode);

        if (document.selection.createRange().text == sValue) {
            sValue = sKey;
        }

        else {
            sValue = sValue + sKey;
        }

        var re = new RegExp("^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?$");
        if (!sValue.match(re))
            window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
```

And I set that to my button in c# code behind with a

```
    private void AddAttributes()
    {
        txtRate.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "fnCurrencyOnly(this)");
    }
```

And this works as long as you are typing the whole number from beginning to end. But if you have 100.00 for example, and stick your cursor between the 1 and zero and type 2, to try and make the value 1200.00 (which is perfectly valid) it won't let you type the 2. The reason for this is in the javascript function, it does the svalue + skey thing, which just tacks what you are typing on to the end. So in this case it is actually validating 100.002, which of course is wrong. I couldn't figure out a way to check on keypress what the value is going to be and check it against the regex. I know I can do it on keyup, but then how do I revert back to the old value if it is not valid?

Comment: Quick note: you don't say in your question what browsers you're targeting, but they're HTML5 only you should use the pattern attribute of `input` instead. Much simpler.

Comment: Sorry, I am targeting IE10 an up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found my own answer:

```
    function doGetCaretPosition(oField) {
        // Initialize
        var iCaretPos = 0;

        // IE Support
        if (document.selection) { 
            oField.focus(); // Set focus on the element
            var oSel = document.selection.createRange(); // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
            oSel.moveStart("character", -oField.value.length); // Move selection start to 0 position
            iCaretPos = oSel.text.length; // The caret position is selection length
        }

        // Firefox support
        else if (oField.selectionStart || oField.selectionStart == "0") {
            iCaretPos = oField.selectionStart;
        }

        // Return results
        return (iCaretPos);
    }

    function fnCurrencyOnly(o) {
        var sValue = o.value;
        var sKey = String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode);
        var pos = doGetCaretPosition(o);

        if (document.selection.createRange().text == sValue) {
            sValue = sKey;
        }
        else {
            sValue = sValue.substr(0, pos) + sKey + sValue.substr(pos);
        }

        var re = new RegExp("^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?$");

        if (!sValue.match(re))
            window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
```

From:
https://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2009/04/24/currency-textbox-with-javascript/#comment-2064

Works perfectly, except you can still copy and paste invalid stuff in the box. Will try to find a solution for that next.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to prevent invalid keypresses when checking the value against a regex recently and came up with this to handle paste and selection replacment:

```
function updateOk(e) {
  var k
  if (e.clipboardData) k = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
  else k = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode)
  const start = e.target.selectionStart
  const end = e.target.selectionEnd
  const v = e.target.value
  const n = v.slice(0, start) + k + v.slice(end)

  if (!/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(n)) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

Input element

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="updateOk(event)" onpaste="updateOk(event)"
  placeholder="number with 2 digits"/>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pbatey/wstdLf5b/15/)